# про try-except в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qspinbox

Заполняю список `listShare`, когда длина списка сравнивается с переменной `numParts` вешаю на кнопку функцию `End`, но почему когда срабатывает исключение, то функция `End` все равно выполняется, а мне надо, чтобы программа ждала ввода данных?

ps. Я совсем-совсем новичок, на консоли ее сделал, все работает, но в PyQt5 сложновато.

```
import sys
from formTest import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.numParts = 2
        self.listShare = []
        self.i = 1
        self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Result)
        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)

    def error(self, n):
        self.n = n
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Ошибка ввода!')
        msg.setText('Введите корректные данные!')
        msg.setIcon(msg.Warning)
        msg.exec()
        self.n.setText('')
        self.n.setFocus()

    def Result(self):
        try:
            if self.ui.lineEdit.text()[0] == '0':
                raise Warning
            else:
                if len(self.listShare) < self.numParts:
                    self.listShare.append(int(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
                    self.i += 1
                    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('')
                if len(self.listShare) == self.numParts-1:
                    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.End)

        except:
            self.error(self.ui.lineEdit)

    def End(self):
        self.ui.centralwidget.hide()

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

В PyQt5 вам не понадобится использовать конструкцию `try-except`. Если вам надо вводить числа, лучше использовать виджет `QSpinBox`. Вашу задачу я увидел так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from formTest import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui = self
        self.ui.lineEdit   = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите число")
        self.ui.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("PushButton")
        self.ui.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.lineEdit)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton)


        self.numParts  = 2
        self.listShare = []
        self.i         = 1
        self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Result)
#        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)
        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.Result)

    def error(self, n):
#        self.n = n
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Ошибка ввода!')
        msg.setText('`{}` <- Введите корректные данные!'.format(n))
        msg.setIcon(msg.Warning)
        msg.exec()
#        self.n.setText('')
#        self.n.setFocus()

    def Result(self):
        line = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if line.isdigit() and line != '0':
            if len(self.listShare) < self.numParts:
                self.listShare.append(int(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
                self.i += 1
                self.ui.lineEdit.setText('')
                self.ui.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Введите {} число".format(self.i))

#            if len(self.listShare) == self.numParts-1:  
            if len(self.listShare) == self.numParts:                    # -1:
#                self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.End)  
                 self.End()
        else: self.error(line)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()
        """
        try:
            print("lineEdit.text[0]", self.ui.lineEdit.text()[0])
            if self.ui.lineEdit.text()[0] == '0':
                raise Warning
            else:
                print(self.listShare, self.numParts)
                if len(self.listShare) < self.numParts:
                    self.listShare.append(int(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
                    self.i += 1
                    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('')
                print(self.listShare, self.numParts-1)   
                if len(self.listShare) == self.numParts-1:
                    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.End)

        except:
            print("error")
            self.error(self.ui.lineEdit)
        """ 

    def End(self):
#        self.ui.centralwidget.hide()
        self.ui.lineEdit.hide()
        self.ui.pushButton.hide()
        date = QtWidgets.QLabel("Введенные данные: " + ", ".join([str(i)  for i in self.listShare]))
        self.grid.addWidget(date)


if __name__== "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Влад что не так?